# Compare columns with a tolerated error in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, compare

I have three different seismic catalogs with origin times calculated using different methods, naturally, the calculated values aren't exactly the same with an error of arround 5 seconds.

Catalog_1

```
Index     Time
0  2022-05-01T08:16:55
1  2022-05-01T09:54:01
2  2022-05-01T10:25:49
3  2022-05-01T12:01:55
4  2022-05-01T18:17:23
```

Catalog_2

```
Index     Time
0  2022-05-01T08:16:58.444
1  2022-05-01T10:25:46.939
2  2022-05-01T20:37:17.491
3  2022-05-01T23:34:22.539
```

Catalog_3

```
Index     Time
0  2022-05-01T10:25:48
1  2022-05-01T23:34:20
2  2022-05-02T07:21:51
```

I want to combine these 3 dataframes into a single dataframe that automatically matches the origin times if they have the acceptable error.

Combined_catalog

```
Index     Time_1                Time_2           Time_3
0  2022-05-01T08:16:55  2022-05-01T08:16:58.444  N/A
1  2022-05-01T09:54:01  N/A                      N/A
2  2022-05-01T10:25:49  2022-05-01T10:25:46.939  2022-05-01T10:25:48
3  2022-05-01T12:01:55  N/A                      N/A
4  2022-05-01T18:17:23  N/A                      N/A
5  N/A                  2022-05-01T20:37:17.491  N/A
6  N/A                  2022-05-01T23:34:22.539  2022-05-01T23:34:20
7  N/A                  N/A                      2022-05-02T07:21:51
```

Is there a way to get a result similar to this witout using loops and if's?

Sometimes the catalogs have data from up to 5 years so it might be better to consider a different approach.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is with assumption, when you said **acceptable error**, below **Seconds** are not considered while matching.

Code is a simple **Merge** of all the dataframes done with bit of a time format manipulation in **Time** columns

**Main Code**

```html
Catalog_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['2022-05-01T08:16:55','2022-05-01T09:54:01','2022-05-01T10:25:49',
                             '2022-05-01T12:01:55', '2022-05-01T18:17:23']})

Catalog_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['2022-05-01T08:16:58.444','2022-05-01T10:25:46.939','2022-05-01T20:37:17.491',
                                  '2022-05-01T23:34:22.539']})

Catalog_3 = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['2022-05-01T10:25:48','2022-05-01T23:34:20','2022-05-02T07:21:51']})


pd.merge(
    pd.merge(Catalog_1,
             Catalog_2,
             left_on=pd.to_datetime(Catalog_1['Time']).dt.floor('min'),
             right_on=pd.to_datetime(Catalog_2['Time']).dt.floor('min'),
             how='outer'),
         Catalog_2,
         left_on='key_0',
         right_on=pd.to_datetime(Catalog_2['Time']).dt.floor('min'),
         how='outer'

).drop('key_0',axis=1).rename(columns={'Time_x':'Time_1','Time_y':'Time_2','Time':'Time_3'})

Output:
```

[image]

*If you need **HOUR** level matching only use*

```
pd.to_datetime(Catalog_1['Time']).dt.floor('H')
```

Comment: This worked fine however, sometimes values from the first column appear to be duplicated wich i assume is due to the rounding that happens if there are two events really close to each other, do you know if it is possible to prevent this from happening?

Comment: That is weird, because if you notice during join code is using "pd.to_datetime(Catalog_2['Time']).dt.floor('min')" which essentially trimmed time column till minute. So it will be only true when "time" column in different dataframes are equal till minutes. It might be possible that data itself have duplicate values.

Comment: This is an example https://i.imgur.com/prNmm83.png from the combined catalog.

And this is the dataframe before combining https://i.imgur.com/Ti9XhuY.png

The other catalogs don't seem to have any duplicates aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas round() function and compare() function might be of help here.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.round.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html